# Compiling Apache 2.4 + mod_wsgi for Python 2.7 64bit + Windows from source code

Tags: windows, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

When reading the [documentation](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/master/win32/README.rst) for compiling from source code on Windows, this made me pause:

> Note that Apache Lounge does not provide any Win64 VC9 binaries for
>   Apache 2.4. This means that technically there is no combination
>   available for correctly running mod_wsgi with a Win64 VC9 version of
>   Python 2.6 or 2.7.
>
> History shows that users simply don't want to accept this and don't
>   want to understand that mixing VC9 and VC10 binaries are not
>   guaranteed to work.
>
> The specific issue is that if certain data structures are passed
>   between VC9 and VC10 code, then the application could crash as the
>   data structure layouts for each variant may not be compatible.
>
> As it happens the interface between Apache and Python via mod_wsgi is
>   very minimal and so it is possible that there are no instances of
>   incompatible data structures being passed across the ABI boundary, but
>   that cannot be guaranteed.
>
> So for those who will not accept 'No' as a answer, the following
>   binaries are also provided. Because they are mixing binaries using
>   different ABIs, they may or may not work for your particular
>   cirumstances. You are still welcome to try, but there is no support
>   for using this combination.

My understanding is that Apache24-win64-VC9 (Python 2.7) isn't supported because Apache Lounge has no binaries. And that if I were to compile Apache from source code with VC9 64bit and mod_wsgi with the same compiler, I should be okay. Is this the correct interpretation and has anyone else had experience doing this?

Note: I've actually tried this myself and haven't experienced any issues so far. I'm curious as to if the horrible things described the docs is something that could happen.